# Create round-robin schedule for 10 teams and 6 rounds

Tags: r, excel

I have 10 teams, and I would like to hold a activity to let their battle in the games.

- Teams competes in 6 rounds
- In each round 5 pairs competes
- Only unique pairs

Can I do this in Excel or R?

Comment: Please review this guide (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a good question at SO. If you want to ask a question related to R, here is a great post about how to provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: 10 teams means 9+8+...+1 = 45 unique pairs. 6 rounds at 5 pairs per round = 30 pairs. What additional rules are you applying to achieve the reduction of 15 pairs? Dividing the 10 teams into two groups of 5 would result in 15 pairs per group so 30 pairings overall.

Answer (score 6):

What you need to apply is algorithm scheduling for round-robin tournament. Explanation of algorithm (elements rotation) is pretty easy and can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm). Summarising, having 14 teams, we arrange them in matrix as follows.

[image]

Then algorithm does specific rotation, keeping first element in the same spot:
[image]

[image]

Here is reproduced solution done with R. Below example is for all combinations, but you can customise to your needs (n=10, r=13) or run for all rounds and pick-up random 6 rounds

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 14
teams <- 1:n
r <- 13


rounds <- list()
for( i in 1:r){
  round <- 
    data.frame(
      round = i,
      team1 = teams[1:(n/2)], 
      team2 = rev(teams)[1:(n/2)])
  rounds[[i]] <- round
  teams <- c( teams[1],  last(teams), head(teams[-1],-1) ) 
}

rr <- bind_rows(rounds)
head(rr)

# round team1 team2
# 1     1     1    14
# 2     1     2    13
# 3     1     3    12
# 4     1     4    11
# 5     1     5    10
# 6     1     6     9
```

Enjoy!